# Converting 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte>' to 'System.Drawing.Image'

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-recognition

I'm making a face recognition in C#.
How can I solve this error?

> Error 4    Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Image'

for this code:

```
cameraBox1.Image = Frame;
names = "" ;
User.Clear();
```

Comment: Does `Emgu.CV.Image` inherit from `System.Drawing.Image`? If yes, then most likely you just need to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` like `cameraBox1` doesn't accept `Emgu.CV.Image` directly. You must convert it to `System.Drawing.Image` like this `cameraBox1.Image = Frame.ToBitmap();`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

a) Image class [Bitmap Property](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/792e25d7-4ae8-52c3-eadb-c05ee7b7919f.htm):

```
cameraBox1.Image = Frame.Bitmap;
```

Wraps Bitmap around Image pixel data. No copy involved.

b) Image class [ToBitmap() method](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/058c70e1-9b5c-5e54-0e43-63a761ede9f7.htm):

```
cameraBox1.Image = Frame.ToBitmap();
```

Copies pixel data from Image into new Bitmap.

Which way you choose depends on your needs. a) is faster but creates shared memory which is more difficult to deal with.